# How to use re.compile to format split function

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a string and not split something in quotes. I've done some reasearch and everything has used the regex compilee method. Can anyone explain to me how this works? I researched about the regex module but I did not find how to use compile.

> my research website:
>
> > www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Comment: @MichaelButscher I always compile my regular expressions in Python.  It's a good habit to get into.

Comment: Just do `r = re.compile("text")` where `"text"` is the regular expression string.  Then you can use `r` as a regular expression, e.g. `r.search(s)` etc.

Comment: @TomKarzes In my opinion it isn't needed for small scripts where a pattern is only used once anyway and, as I said, for beginners who shouldn't care about the additional code necessary to compile and then use the pattern.

Comment: @TomKarzes can you please post an answer as an example? It would really help, thanks!!!

Comment: @AlexLiu10101 Ok, I'll post a very simple example.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks for the help and support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple example of how to use `re.compile` to compile a regular expression and use it to search strings:

```
import re

r = re.compile("^ab.*yz$")

for s in ["abc", "xyz", "a12z", "ab456yz"]:
    if r.search(s):
        print("T", s)
    else:
        print("F", s)
```

The output is:

```
F abc
F xyz
F a12z
T ab456yz
```

This just compiles the regular expression `"^ab.*yz$"` and saves the result as `r`.  It then searches 4 strings for a match, printing the results.  The regular expression I used is anchored at the start (`^`) and end (`$`), and matches any string that starts with `ab` and ends with `yz`.